# How to fix connection issues while sending heavy files to hive table?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hdfs, bigdata, hiveql

I have files on hdfs that I want to put in a Hive table. The operation is performed by Spark batch in a java app.
The code performing the task is the following :

```java
[...]

final Dataset<File> fileDs = rawDs.map(record -> {
        return FileService.map(record.getList(2));
      }, Encoders.bean(File.class));

final Dataset<Row> fileDsWithId = fileDs.withColumn("id", functions.lit(id));
fileDsWithId.repartition(fileDsWithId.col("id")); 

fileWithId.write().mode(SaveMode.Append)
  .format("orc")
  .partitionBy("id")
  .option("path", hdfs://..../mydatabase.db/mytable")
  .saveAsTable("mydatabase.mytable");
```

When I use a small file (1 or 2 lines of data) the app is working fine, job ending successfully within 30 seconds. The table is created in Hive and I can display data using a Select * query. It's also working when the table already exists. Datas are simply added to the existing ones. 
The generate table's structures in hive seems fine. It matches my datas.

But when I try to process a bigger file (3.7Mo with about 1000 lines of data) the job fails after 15 minutes. The corresponding orc file is created in hdfs but it's empty and Hive doesn't know about it.

The log file is showing several errors like these :

```
2019-05-31 14:20:07,500 - [ERROR] [                           dispatcher-event-loop-3] pache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClusterScheduler - [{}] - Lost executor 31 on XXXXXX: Container marked as failed: container_e71_1559121287708_0019_02_000032 on host: XXXXXXXXX. Exit status: 143. Diagnostics: Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143.
Killed by external signal
[...]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at org.spark_project.guava.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.sendRpcSync(TransportClient.java:273)
        at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doSparkAuth(AuthClientBootstrap.java:105)
        at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doBootstrap(AuthClientBootstrap.java:79)
...
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
        at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
...
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        ... 1 more
[...]       
        2019-05-31 14:20:17,898 - [ERROR] [                                shuffle-client-4-1]    org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient - [{}] - Failed to send RPC 9035939448873337359 to XXXXXXXX: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelExceptionsg
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(...)(Unknown Source)
2019-05-31 14:20:17,899 - [ERROR] [          Executor task launch worker for task 244] apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory - [{}] - Exception while bootstrapping client after 5999 mssg
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 9035939448873337359 to XXXXXXXXX: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.spark_project.guava.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.sendRpcSync(TransportClient.java:273)
        at org.apache.spark.network.sasl.SaslClientBootstrap.doBootstrap(SaslClientBootstrap.java:70)
        at org.apache.spark.network.crypto.AuthClientBootstrap.doSaslAuth(AuthClientBootstrap.java:115)
     ...
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to send RPC 9035939448873337359 to XXXXXXXXXXXX: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClient.lambda$sendRpc$2(TransportClient.java:237)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:122)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetFailure(AbstractChannel.java:852)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:738)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1251)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:733)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:725)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$1900(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:35)
...
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        ... 1 more
[...]       
2019-05-31 14:20:22,907 - [INFO ] [                             Block Fetch Retry-6-1] .apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher - [{}] - Retrying fetch (2/3) for 1 outstanding blocks after 5000 mssg
2019-05-31 14:20:27,909 - [ERROR] [                             Block Fetch Retry-6-2] .apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher - [{}] - Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks (after 2 retries)sg
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to XXXXXXXXX
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
...
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connexion refused: XXXXXXXX
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:257)
...
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        ... 2 more
[...]       
        2019-05-31 14:20:32,915 - [WARN ] [          Executor task launch worker for task 244]              org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager - [{}] - Failed to fetch remote block broadcast_2_piece0 from BlockManagerId(1, XXXXXXX, 44787, None) (failed attempt 1)sg
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:642)
...
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:338)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to XXXXXXXXX
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:232)
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:182)
...
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:144)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connexion refused: XXXXXXXX
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
...
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:131)
        ... 2 more
```

I don't understand what's going on there. I have checked for memory issues but it seems fine. These machines are used to process way bigger files (usually dozens of gigabytes).
Why are the connection lost/denied/reset ? Is there any issue with Spark creating the table scheme beforehand that would explain this ?

---

`UPDATED after Ram Ghadiyaram's answer :`
I've tried setting `spark.network.timeout` to 6000s. No other timeout setting is configured in the environnement.
The result seems to be the same. The job fails after 10 minutes showing the same errors in log file :  "connection reset by peer", "fail to send RPC" and so on

Setting `spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout`, `spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs`,  `spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout`, `spark.rpc.askTimeout` and `spark.rpc.lookupTimeout` to the same value (6000s) doesn't seem to work either.

I think my dataset is too messy to be handled properly anyway. I'll try changing the data model and then run the app again with these timeout settings.

---

`Updated 01/07/2019 :`
I have simplified the data model. The model was complex, leading to some empty structure in the dataset because the system couldn't link some fields by inheritance. I have flattened the structure so that every possible type is present as an actual attribute of the generic class, and so I removed inheritance.

To wrap it up, something like that:
File.class
  |-field1
  |-field2
  |-field3
  |- GenericClass
     |-Class1
     |-Class2
     |-Class3

Instead of an abstract class with some daughters I made a generic one with other classes as attributes.
This is quite dirty (and I don't recommand doing this), but the dataset was much cleaner this way.

I no longer had timeout issues after this change was performed. I guess the previous model was too messy to be efficiently writen by Spark.

I've tried writing in ORC and Avro format and both were okay.
In Avro I managed to write about 300000 lines within a minute, so default timeout settings are no longer a problem.

Comment: i'm not understanding how data modal can cause connection reset by peer error in executor.

Answer (score 0):

> Q:Why are the connection lost/denied/reset ?

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
        at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:205)
```

Seems like its typical timeout issue for large or heavy work load.

I dont know which version of spark you are using. but its failing here.
basically what it does is it will wait for some time (default timeout) and it will fail. see [ThreadUtils](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/ThreadUtils.scala)

```
/**
   * Preferred alternative to `Await.result()`.
   *
   * This method wraps and re-throws any exceptions thrown by the underlying `Await` call, ensuring
   * that this thread's stack trace appears in logs.
   *
   * In addition, it calls `Awaitable.result` directly to avoid using `ForkJoinPool`'s
   * `BlockingContext`. Codes running in the user's thread may be in a thread of Scala ForkJoinPool.
   * As concurrent executions in ForkJoinPool may see some [[ThreadLocal]] value unexpectedly, this
   * method basically prevents ForkJoinPool from running other tasks in the current waiting thread.
   * In general, we should use this method because many places in Spark use [[ThreadLocal]] and it's
   * hard to debug when [[ThreadLocal]]s leak to other tasks.
   */
  @throws(classOf[SparkException])
  def awaitResult[T](awaitable: Awaitable[T], atMost: Duration): T = {
    try {
      // `awaitPermission` is not actually used anywhere so it's safe to pass in null here.
      // See SPARK-13747.
      val awaitPermission = null.asInstanceOf[scala.concurrent.CanAwait]
      awaitable.result(atMost)(awaitPermission)
    } catch {
      case e: SparkFatalException =>
        throw e.throwable
      // TimeoutException is thrown in the current thread, so not need to warp the exception.
      case NonFatal(t) if !t.isInstanceOf[TimeoutException] =>
        throw new SparkException("Exception thrown in awaitResult: ", t)
    }
  }
```

you have to increase timeouts see [networking docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking)

> `spark.network.timeout`   120s    Default timeout for all network
>   interactions. This config will be used in place of
>   `spark.core.connection.ack.wait.timeout`,
>   `spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs`,
>   `spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout`, `spark.rpc.askTimeout` or
>   `spark.rpc.lookupTimeout` if they are not configured.

---

> To sumup :  For small workloads timeout is enough for large work loads
>   time out needs to be increasaed.

Comment: Have you tried increasing time outs? Pls Post the results

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I was out off the office for a while.

No timeouts settings have been configured previously in the environnement so I have set spark.network.timeout = 6000s an re-run the app. 

It doesn't seem to change the outcome. After about 10min the job fail and the same kind of errors appears in the log file : "connection reset by peer", " Failed to send RPC" and so on.

Comment: ok please try with other time out options i mentioned there like spark.rpc.askTimeout

Comment: if you are okay please care to [accept answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)